# ValidateNumber localization i Flow

Tags: flow-framework

Am I using this right? For a float value. `12,12` get rejected, `12.12` does not. I want the opposite to be true.

```
@Flow\Validate(type="Number", options={ "locale"="de_DE" })
```

Reference [here](http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/2.0/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartV/ValidatorReference.html#numbervalidator) (but no usage example ><)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually validation is too late. What you want is map a string `12,12`to a float value `12.12`. This comes before validation. So you need to configure the PropertyMapper. See comments in the `\TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\FloatConverter` which are pretty extensive.

Roughly this is what you need:

```
protected function initializeCreateAction() {
    $this->arguments['newBid']->getPropertyMappingConfiguration()->
        forProperty('yourPropertyThatShouldBeFloat')->
        setTypeConverterOption('TYPO3\Flow\Property\TypeConverter\FloatConverter', 'locale', 'de');
}
```

For the additional question of accepting both formats `12,12` and `12.12` as float `12.12` you probably need to write your own FloatConverter that checks for the existence of a comma and does either of the two conversions.

Comment: But `12.12` --> `1,212.00` with this?